# Unrequested debugging Info in Powershell console

Tags: debugging, powershell, console, winscp, winscp-net

I'm having a nuisance issue I'd like to eliminate where I get debugging info I am not asking for in a Powershell console and ISE.  It's a nuisance in that it gets in the way of my desired debugging info.

I'm not clear if this is specific to the tool I am scripting (WinSCP), or a more generic PowerShell behavior.

In a nutshell,  `WinSCP.Session.Open` events don't write out anything out (good!), but the `Close()` and `Dispose()` methods are quite chatty, with the below appearing in my console on each invocation.

At first I thought this might be the consequence of including the statements in a `finally` block, but moving them to the `try` block yields the same nuisance behavior.

Based on a similar, but not identical issue, I checked out the "preference variables".  My stock values are listed at the very end, the only one I tried to change to no avail was the "Warning Preference" to "Silently COntinue", which had no effect

Run-Example:

```
PS F:\> getFirewallContents "AAA" 255.255.227.254
Attempting Session.Open  AAA  |  255.255.227.254
Completed  Session.Open  AAA  |  255.255.227.254
/var/db/commits exists, last write: 5/8/2015 11:33:22 AM
Closing Session  AAA

... two stanzas that follow are the undesired output ......    

MemberType          : Method
OverloadDefinitions : {System.Void Close()}
TypeNameOfValue     : System.Management.Automation.PSMethod
Value               : System.Void Close()
Name                : Close
IsInstance          : True

MemberType          : Method
OverloadDefinitions : {System.Void Dispose()}
TypeNameOfValue     : System.Management.Automation.PSMethod
Value               : System.Void Dispose()
Name                : Dispose
IsInstance          : True

Closed  Session  AAA
```

---

```psh
function getFirewallContents ([string] $fw_name, [string] $fw_ip) {
    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
    $xferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions

    $sessionOptions.HostName = $fw_ip
    $sessionOptions.UserName = "NOPE"
    $sessionOptions.Password = "NOT TELLING"
    $sessionOptions.Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    $sessionOptions.GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = $TRUE

    $remotefile = "/var/db/commits"

    Try {
        Write-Host  "Attempting Session.Open " $fw_name " | " $sessionOptions.HostName 

        $session.Open($sessionOptions)

        Write-Host  "Completed  Session.Open " $fw_name " | " $sessionOptions.HostName      

        if ($session.FileExists($remotefile)) {
            Write-Host "$remotefile exists, last write:" $session.GetFileInfo($remotefile).LastWriteTime
        } else {
            Write-Host "$remotefile NOT FOUND"
        }
    } Catch {
        Write-Host "Something bad happened"
    } Finally {
        Write-Host "Closing Session  $fw_name "
        $session.Close
        $session.Dispose
        Write-Host "Closed  Session  $fw_name "
    }
}
```

---

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
ConfirmPreference              High
DebugPreference                SilentlyContinue
ErrorActionPreference          Continue
ProgressPreference             Continue
VerbosePreference              SilentlyContinue
WarningPreference              Continue     (Tried Silently Continue, no effect)
WhatIfPreference               False
```

Comment: Send the output to the bit-bucket. `$session.Close | Out-Null`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing brackets in call to `.Close` and `.Dispose`. So you are actually *not calling* the methods at all, but rather taking an address of the methods and not using it. PowerShell prints the "expression" results on a console as a last resort.

The correct syntax is:

```
$session.Close()
$session.Dispose()
```

Comment: This was a big learning moment for me, thank you,m thank you!!!!      Of course, this is also why I had a couple hundred processes showing up in Process Monitor.   (Didn't notice at the time). It's a weird response the way it presents the info, cause it doesn't really make it clear what you thought happened did not -- not clear that its a "WARNING" or "ERROR", not simply "INFO" or "DEBUG" info.     Again, this will be a great learning moment.  Glad the other poster deleted his response, although that was useful info, even if it was not correct after all.

Comment: Hey!  I just realized why your name seemed familiar!    Double thanks!